# Sidekiq process failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a rails 4.1 application with Sidekiq 3.3.2 in production mode with default config.

Everything works fine, but sometimes, I see in Sidekiq admin panel that Sidekiq process, not listed in the "busy" in the panel and does not exist in the list of processes.
That seems like a sidekiq's process has been fail.
In the log there is no error entries.

How can I make that stable?

Comment: It's difficult to help you if you don't provide more context.

Comment: You're not giving enough detail to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [known problem](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1871). Hard loaded Sidekiq worker is disappear sometimes from busy list but still working fine.

I known issue marked as fixed but seems like it appear again and again. Just don't worry about it and use `ps aux | grep sidekiq` to check running Sidekiq workers in this case.